# Trying To Get Bootstrap Columns to Collapse How I Want

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am struggling with getting the bootstrap layout that I want. Here is what I am hoping to achieve.

What it should look like on large screens (I know how to do this):

```
-------------------------------------------------------
|   Column 1  |  Column 2   |  Column 3  |  Column 4  |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

What it should look like on medium screens (This is where I am stuck):

```
-----------------------------------------
|   Column 1  |  Column 3  |  Column 4  |
|   Column 2  |            |            |
-----------------------------------------
```

What it should look like on small screens (I know how to do this):

```
---------------
|   Column 1  |
---------------
|   Column 2  |
---------------
|   Column 3  |
---------------
|   Column 4  |
---------------
```

Any suggestions????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">Column 1</div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">Column 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">Column 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, because this one is best practise.

Comment: Thanks! I actually saw your initial answer and it got me thinking about it differently and I was able to get it figured out before I even saw your 2nd answer. I was pushing and pulling columns all over the place when the actual solution was much more simple.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  background: #123;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 grid">Column 1</div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 grid">Column 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 grid">Column 3</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 grid">Column 4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```